# Android emulator plugin - Different root folder

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm trying to create a Jenkins build task for my Android project.
The first task is to check the code out from git.
Because the project consist out of more components than only an Android project (also a Java backend and other clients) the project is not in the root folder but in: `/Android/`

After the git checkout I added the task `Install Android project prerequisites`
but now I allways get the following error:

`[android] Searching for Android projects...
 [android] No Android projects found; wont install any dependencies.`

Also when I use the gradle plugin. It can't find the gradlew file.

I tried to check `Use custom workspace` but this creates `Android/Android`.
How to change the working directory of all the build steps?

Adding a shell command `cd Android` does not help...

*edit:*
For now I moved the files using `rsync -va --delete-after Android/* .`
Gradle works but `Install Android project prerequisites` still can't find the Android project. Does this plugin support gradle or does it still needs a "project.properties" or "default.properties" file (than this plugin which is already full of bugs is totally useless).

Comment: For now I manually installed all Android SDK's on the server....

Comment: please give me some information to fix this issue. What you manually installed?

Comment: It is not a fix because it will not download the required sdk's automatically. I just installed them manualy on the server using the SDK mannager. I think the plugin does not support a subfolder.